# AWS CodeArtifact for Ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, aws-codeartifact, gem-fury

Based on the AWS CodeArtifact FAQ https://aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/faq/ I do not see Ruby gems in the list of features. Is it possible to use AWS CodeArtifact instead of Gemfury?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, although I wish it were. I see only a handful of repo types when getting connection instructions:

- npm
- mvn
- gradle
- pip
- twine
- nuget